# Rendering elements in MyFaces 1.1.1

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener, rendered-attribute, conditional-rendering, jsf-1.1

I am trying to create a simple jsf page where I have a dropdown whose value determines which label to render. Initially all the labels' render is set as false through the backing bean constructor. But I have called submit onchange which sets the respective values to true for the labels. I have set the scope of the backing bean as **session** so that the value being set does not get removed onchange. However the label does not get rendered onchange. Below is the code snippet for the jsf page:

```
<h:form>

    <h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputLabel styleClass="captionOutputField" value="Select Report Type:" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectedMenu" onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{ReportHealth.typeSelectDropDownChange}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="empty" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="daily" itemValue="daily" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="weekly" itemValue="weekly" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="monthly" itemValue="monthly" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{ReportHealth.daily}">
    <h3>MENU 0</h3>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{ReportHealth.weekly}">
    <h3>MENU 1</h3>
</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{ReportHealth.monthly}">
    <h3>MENU 2</h3>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Here is the backing bean:

```
public class ReportHealth implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private boolean weekly;
private boolean monthly;
private boolean daily;
private String menuValue;



public ReportHealth() {
    weekly = false;
    monthly = false;
    daily = false;
}

public String getMenuValue() {
    return menuValue;
}

public void setMenuValue(String menuValue) {
    this.menuValue = menuValue;
}

public boolean isWeekly() {
    return weekly;
}

public void setWeekly(boolean weekly) {
    this.weekly = weekly;
}

public boolean isMonthly() {
    return monthly;
}

public void setMonthly(boolean monthly) {
    this.monthly = monthly;
}

public boolean isDaily() {
    return daily;
}

public void setDaily(boolean daily) {
    this.daily = daily;
}

public void typeSelectDropDownChange(ValueChangeEvent e)
{
    String typeSelectVal = e.getNewValue().toString();
    if(typeSelectVal!=null && typeSelectVal.equalsIgnoreCase("daily"))
    {
        setDaily(true);
        setWeekly(false);
        setMonthly(false);
    }
    else if(typeSelectVal!=null && typeSelectVal.equalsIgnoreCase("weekly"))
    {
        setDaily(false);
        setWeekly(true);
        setMonthly(false);
    }
    else if(typeSelectVal!=null && typeSelectVal.equalsIgnoreCase("monthly"))
    {
        setDaily(false);
        setWeekly(false);
        setMonthly(true);
    }
    else
    {
        setDaily(false);
        setWeekly(false);
        setMonthly(false);
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with my code. Instead of putting the labels in `<H3>`tags. I needed to put it in `<h:outputText>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you are using so complicated code for simple task.
Here is what you need

```
<h:form>
 <h:panelGroup>
 <h:outputLabel styleClass="captionOutputField" value="Select Report Type:"/>
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectedMenu" value="#{reportHealth.menuValue}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="empty" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="daily" itemValue="daily" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="weekly" itemValue="weekly" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="monthly" itemValue="monthly" />
    <f:ajax render="@form">
                    </f:ajax>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{reportHealth.menuValue eq 'daily'}">
  <h3>MENU 0</h3>
 </h:panelGroup>
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{reportHealth.menuValue eq 'weekly'}">
  <h3>MENU 1</h3>
 </h:panelGroup>
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{reportHealth.menuValue eq 'monthly'}">
  <h3>MENU 2</h3>
 </h:panelGroup>
 </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

and Bean will be

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ReportHealth implements Serializable{

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private String menuValue;

 public String getMenuValue() {
    return menuValue;
 }

 public void setMenuValue(String menuValue) {
    this.menuValue = menuValue;
 }

}
```

Comment: OP is using jurassic JSF 1.x. The <f:ajax> and @ViewScoped didn't exist in JSF 1.x. So your answer won't run in JSF 1.x at all. For the remainder I agree those additional boolean properties is unnecessarily overcomplicated.